# serial key validation in c#

Tags: c#

I completed my project in C#.Net. 
I Added a serial key in it. 
At the time of installation it asks me for the key. 
The key format is also given by me, but I don't know how to validate that key.
Please give me some way how to validate that key.
Now my key is validated by visual studio or I don't know who. How is the key's validation done?
But I want to do the validation by my own. Is it possible? And if yes, how?

i added the customer information dialog.
and format is given by using the serial number template.
but for validation it create the problem that visual studio's logic is so simple & it is if the some of digits is / by 7 then key is valid.so i want to use  the my logic like use sha1,MD5 so where i have to do coding.
The design of the customer info dialog is not show,if it is shown then i do the coding on validate button.
But now what i have to do?

Comment: You added a `serial key` and you dont know how to validate it? You also say that the `key format` is given by you? Then you already know the format, you can check any input key whether that complies your format or not. If you mean something else by 'verification', explain in your question

Comment: i added the customer information dialog.and format is given by using the serial number template.but for validation it create the problem that visual studio,s logic is so simple & it is if the some of digits is / by 7 then key is valid.so i want to use  the my logic like use sha1,MD5 so where i have to do coding.

Comment: Please mark as answered,based on which you find is the correct answer.This may help others.

Answer (score 0):

to write this code you can make an md5 hash according to an algorithm of your own so every user must have a key related to lets say his user name and email address that will unlock if the key is typed correctly. lets say if you have a user name "muster" and an email address "mymail@mail.web" you can combine it in an algorith of your own "simplest one for example is concatination: "mustermymail@mail.web" now encoding md5 hash to it will give a 32 char "9192ec1632022ab6b3706dc053d7b20f" which forms a serial and this serial can't be decrypted unless you know the algorithm that it was encrypted first.

to make an md5 hash value try this:

```
string text="mustermymail@mail.web";
byte []bytes=System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
byte []md5Bytes=System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
string md5Text=System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(md5Bytes);
```

Check : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielfe/archive/2005/07/10/437293.aspx for starters...